# how to use clipboard.js in same class in <p1>

Tags: javascript, php, html

[https://i.imgur.com/r3tTCuh.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEZzE.jpg)

this my html script

```
<td><p1><?php echo $result->bn_nomor;?></p1></td>
<td> <button class="btn1 badge badge-info">Copy Nomor</button>
```

and this my javascript

```
<script>
var clipboard=new Clipboard(".btn1",{
  target:function(){
    return document.querySelector("p1")
  }
});
clipboard.on("success",function(o){
  console.log(o)
}),
clipboard.on("error",function(o){
  console.log(o)
});
</script>
```

I cant copy one by one data which results from $ result-> bn_number;
only one can copy , the other cant i copy, I want to be in copy one by one the result data with same class.. thanks

Comment: Can you re-structure/write your last sentence? It's quite hard to understand...

Answer (score 0):

You could add a loop in [jquery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/):

```
var obj = {
  "flammable": "inflammable",
  "duh": "no duh"
};

$.each( obj, function( key, value ) {
  alert( key + ": " + value );
});
```